# HTML Service Assign URL to Image

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 4 images that all have hyperlinks associated with them. I'm trying to pull the image link and the hyperlink from a Google Spreadsheet to be displayed in the web app.

The hyperlinks are pulling over just fine but I get an error when I try to pull the link for the image. I've hunted online and all solutions don't seem to work for me. How can I pull a link from the Google Spreadsheet and set it as the source for the image?

This is the error I receive: Cannot set property 'src' of null

Here's a chunk of my code:

```
<div align="center">
  <div class="contener_slideshow">
    <div class="contener_slide">
      <div class="slid_1"><a href="" target="blank" id="link1"><img id="oneS" src=""></a></div>
      <div class="slid_2"><a href="" target="blank" id="link2"><img id="twoS" src=""></a></div>
      <div class="slid_3"><a href="" target="blank" id="link3"><img id="threeS" src=""></a></div>
      <div class="slid_4"><a href="" target="blank" id="link4"><img id="fourS" src=""></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
function onSuccess(data){

  var oneS = document.getElementById('link1');
  oneS.innerHTML = data[1][2];


try{  
  document.getElementById("oneS").src = data[1][1];

}catch(error){
  alert(error);
}
}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
  .getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `innerHTML` in `data[1][2]` must be wrong.  Use a `console.log()` statement to find out what the value of `data[1][2]` is:

```
<script>
  function onSuccess(data){
    console.log('data: ' + data);
    console.log('data[1][2]: ' + data[1][2]);

    var oneS = document.getElementById('link1');
    oneS.innerHTML = data[1][2];
```

Open the browser's console, run the code and see what has printed to the log.

This Line:

```
oneS.innerHTML = data[1][2];
```

Deletes all the original HTML out of the `<a>` tag with the id `link1`, and replaces it with whatever `data[1][2]` returns.  So if `data[1][2]` is empty, then there is no `<img>` tag anymore with the `oneS` id.  So, when you try to get it, it's null.  Therefore the error msg:

> Cannot set property 'src' of null

I'm assuming that `data[1][2]` is just the link, not the link inside of the HTML.  What you are assigning for HTML can't just be URL address.  What you are assigning needs to be:

```
<img id="oneS" src="the URL Here">
```

Hard coded it would look like this:

```
oneS.innerHTML = <img id="oneS" src="the URL Here">;
```

If what you are getting out of the spreadsheet is just the URL, you can use a text formula to create the HTML

```
var htmlToInject = "<img id='oneS' src='" + data[1][1] + "'>";
document.getElementById("oneS").src = htmlToInject;
```